# Movie night idea

Tags: discussion, community-event

Over on literature we’re trying to get a book club going.  It’s going rough but we’re working on it.  The idea that I had is something… similar but different.  Every week (or month, whatever timeline you want) the community would vote for a movie to watch.  Then at a designated time you would schedule a chat session for people to talk while watching the movie together (or perhaps schedule multiple chat sessions to cater to those in different time zones).

Any questions brought up while watching could be asked in chat, or asked on the main site.

Any details would be completely up to the community to decide on, and that's only if you all **want** to do something like this.

Comment: Discussing a movie everybody just watched is bound to lead to some interesting questions (depending on what movie we watch), sounds interesting!

Answer (score 2):

Having several people to start their own copy of the movie at the exact same time won't work. Everyone will be out of sync, which reduces the benefit of chat, especially due to minute-early spoilers.

I think our best option is streaming. The legality is questionable, although there is a [massive number of public domain films](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_in_the_public_domain_in_the_United_States) which would be perfectly legal to stream.

Comment: Netflix offer synchronized streaming of their movies I think - although this would currently limit this to North America I think - but they are expanding in Europe soon.