# Could a question of the week be asked on this site?

Tags: discussion

Over on the Sci-fi&Fantasy StackExchange I noticed they have a question of the week feature. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-feb-20
This can really help to generate questions and I think it could be used in conjunction with DForks idea of a movie night [Movie night idea](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/movie-night-idea)

Would this be possible to do on this site? I ask because I noticed there aren't really as many questions being generated on this site and I think this could help. Maybe an award of reputation points instead of a prize would work.

Comment: There should be no meddling with reputation points (and badges), except as part of normal Q&A (and QA). There should be other rewards that won't result in impurifying the precious bodily fluids.

Comment: I'm certainly not suggesting putting Floride into anyone's water. I was simply suggesting a method that didn't require money. So I guess I was thinking of something more like a bonus awarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must remember that we are a Beta site, so comparing ourselves to a more established non-beta site like Sci-Fi is slightly unfair on us.  Sci-Fi had a beta period of around 10 months, and left beta 2 months ago (according to Area51). Movies & TV is drawing close to 3 months in beta.

That said, I don't see why we could not do this.  We could brainstorm the topic of the week on Meta so that it is not one person's responsibility to keep this going.  The mods would also have to ask about reputation point prizes - as I for one do not know how this would work.

Is 'topic of the week' realistic for us, or should we aim lower - 2 weeks?  I guess a month is too long.

Do people have some topic ideas or examples to share?

Answer (score 1):

I think we could, we just need community support and participation.  Specifically, we need someone, preferably someones, to actually run this.  I would personally love to see this happen, and I would do my best to participate.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not out of the realm of possibility but obviously a lot more difficult for this site at this point in time.

My personal view is to either tie this in with, or separately work out something with major releases that are up and coming (Dark Knight Rises, Avengers, MiB3, etc)  Or even work out our own [**community ads**](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2468/community-promotion-ads-2012).